# CefSharp offscreen with .net core 2.0 Runtime Error , System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp.Core,

Tags: javascript, c#, .net-core, cefsharp, cefsharp.offscreen

I am getting this error

**System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp.Core, Version=63.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=40c4b6fc221f4138'. The system cannot find the file specified.'**

I am trying to run the **cefsharp.minimalexample.offscreen** program in **.net core 2.0.** in visual studio 2017

what I have done so far

1 . Created .net core console application

2 . Installed NuGet packages Cefsharp.Offscreen (which installs the dependencies cefsharp.common and redist)

3 . Installed Microsoft.windows.compatibility nuget package to get the system.drawing in .net core (It was not working with System.Drawing.Common as the Cefsharp **ScreenshotAsync** function using system.drawing)

These steps will clear all the errors and the project will build successfully.

I am getting the above mentioned error.
I have checked all the required files mentioned in the Cefsharp documentation  in the current running folder (debug). All files are available ,Still error is not going away.

It works fine in old Dot net versions 4.6.

I could not find any helping documents for implementing cefsharp.offscreen with .net core any where.

This is the code from the example provided in the Cefsharp.offscreen.

Please let me know if you can shed some light on this issue. Thanks in advance.

```
public class Program
{
    private static ChromiumWebBrowser browser;

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const string testUrl = "https://www.google.com/";

        Console.WriteLine("This example application will load {0}, take a screenshot, and save it to your desktop.", testUrl);
        Console.WriteLine("You may see Chromium debugging output, please wait...");
        Console.WriteLine();

        var settings = new CefSettings()
        {
            //By default CefSharp will use an in-memory cache, you need to specify a Cache Folder to persist data
            CachePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "CefSharp\\Cache")
        };

        //Perform dependency check to make sure all relevant resources are in our output directory.
        Cef.Initialize(settings, performDependencyCheck: true, browserProcessHandler: null);

        // Create the offscreen Chromium browser.
        browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser(testUrl);

        // An event that is fired when the first page is finished loading.
        // This returns to us from another thread.
        browser.LoadingStateChanged += BrowserLoadingStateChanged;

        // We have to wait for something, otherwise the process will exit too soon.
        Console.ReadKey();

        // Clean up Chromium objects.  You need to call this in your application otherwise
        // you will get a crash when closing.
        Cef.Shutdown();
    }

    private static void BrowserLoadingStateChanged(object sender, LoadingStateChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Check to see if loading is complete - this event is called twice, one when loading starts
        // second time when it's finished
        // (rather than an iframe within the main frame).
        if (!e.IsLoading)
        {
            // Remove the load event handler, because we only want one snapshot of the initial page.
            browser.LoadingStateChanged -= BrowserLoadingStateChanged;

            var scriptTask = browser.EvaluateScriptAsync("document.getElementById('lst-ib').value = 'CefSharp Was Here!'");

            scriptTask.ContinueWith(t =>
            {
                //Give the browser a little time to render
                Thread.Sleep(500);
                // Wait for the screenshot to be taken.
                var task = browser.ScreenshotAsync();
                task.ContinueWith(x =>
                {
                    // Make a file to save it to (e.g. C:\Users\jan\Desktop\CefSharp screenshot.png)
                    var screenshotPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "CefSharp screenshot.png");

                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("Screenshot ready. Saving to {0}", screenshotPath);

                    // Save the Bitmap to the path.
                    // The image type is auto-detected via the ".png" extension.
                    task.Result.Save(screenshotPath);

                    // We no longer need the Bitmap.
                    // Dispose it to avoid keeping the memory alive.  Especially important in 32-bit applications.
                    task.Result.Dispose();

                    Console.WriteLine("Screenshot saved.  Launching your default image viewer...");

                    // Tell Windows to launch the saved image.
                    Process.Start(screenshotPath);

                    Console.WriteLine("Image viewer launched.  Press any key to exit.");
                }, TaskScheduler.Default);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: .net core does not support VC++ which CefSharp requres, see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#need-to-knowlimitations

Comment: You should be able to use CefGlue or ChromiumFx

Comment: .Net Core 3 adds support for VC++(windows only), it's now possible to use CefSharp,  see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample#net-core-support for an example.  Issue https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/2796 has more details.